# Magento 2: Customer dropdown attribute not selecting first option

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, customer-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I have added a new customer attribute which is working fine.

The only thing is that I would like it to **display the first option selected by default** in both admin and frontend side (account create / edit).

How can I achieve this?

This is how my **eav_attribute** table looks like:

```
attribute_id => 200,
entity_type_id => 1,
attribute_code => existing_member,
attrubute_model => null,
backend_model => null,
backend_type => int,
backend_table => null,
frontend_model => null, 
frontend_input => select,
frontend_label => Existing Member,
frontend_class => null,
source_model => Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table,
is_required => 0,
is_user_defined => 1,
default_value => null,
is_unique => 0,
note => null
```

This is how it is being displayed atm:

Frontend:

[image: magn]

Admin Panel:

[image]

Comment: You need to set default_value => 1

Comment: @RasikMiyani But isn't that referring to a value from an option that doesn't exist? Wouldn't it be "hard-coded" if I put one of the ids from the three options that I have?